# Detect Parse Error in APK Install

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, apk, android-install-apk

I am developing a app manager, an ecosystem for my apps. One of the key feature is app download and update. 
I have successfully implemented the download system but for some reason if the download terminates in between and the app install receives a parse error, can I have a broadcast receiver that receives this event?

Comment: Use a cryptographically-secure hash to validate the download before doing the install, to detect the failed download before doing the install.

Comment: Hey @commonsware, Definitely.. That's in the works, but I was thinking if there's a way to detect the parse error (as a quick fix), similar to what happens on playstore.